# is there a way to reference a json encoded data saved in phpmyadmin database in a php inner join query?

Tags: php, mysql

my name is david, i have the below query and json sample data and i am trying to do a php inner join query. i have a country, state and city drop-down from which users are to select and the id's of the inputs data(country id, state id, city id) gets saved to a customers table in shipping column in the database saved as json objects along with other details.

i need to fetch the id's and compare it with the country, state, city and customers table then echo the specific name of the country, state, city names with that has that id match. pls is this possible. i am new here so i am not sure i wrote this well enough.

my query below

```
$innerJoins = Database::$database->query("SELECT c.*, s.*, t.*, l.* FROM countries c, states s, cities t, customers l WHERE c.country_id=l.shipping.[5] AND s.state_id=l.shipping.[5] AND t.city_id=l.shipping.[3] AND `user_id` = {$customer->user_id}");
           
while($row = $innerJoins->fetch_object()) {
   $joins[] = $row;

}
```

sample json data stored in shipping column

```
{"type":"personal","name":"David Junior","address":"Kingstown estate Ajao","city":"4641","zip":"34567","country":"156","phone":"09048749027","tax_id":"","state":"1066","whatsapp":"09048749027"}
```

please your response will be much appreciated.

note: this is a typical example of what i am trying to achieve below but with json encoded data not individual rows.

```
$orders_result = Database::$database->query("SELECT c.*, s.*, t.*, l.* FROM countries c, states s, cities t, locations l WHERE c.country_id=l.country_id AND s.state_id=l.state_id AND t.city_id=l.city_id AND `user_id` = {$this->user->user_id}");
```

Comment: [MySQL JSON Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html)

Comment: There's no such thing as a a "phpmyadmin database". The database is MySQL, PhpMyAdmin is a web application for querying it.

Comment: IMO should never store delimited data in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's JSON extraction operator [`->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) to access elements of a JSON object.

```
$innerJoins = Database::$database->query("
    SELECT c.*, s.*, t.*, l.* 
    FROM customers l
    JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = l.shipping->>'country'
    JOIN states s ON s.state_id = l.shipping->>'state'
    JOIN cities t ON t.city_id = l.shipping->>'city'
    WHERE `user_id` = {$customer->user_id}");
```

Comment: thanks for your kind response, pls sorry for disturbing you, i'll like to know how to fetch it to a variable. i tried this way but did not get anything result.

Comment: $joins = $innerJoins->num_rows;
           if($joins > 0){

            while($row = $innerJoins->fetch_object()) {
                $cid = $row->country_name;
                $sid = $row->state_name;
                $cit = $row->city_name;
            } 
          }